# Laravel 6.17 to newer version upgrade issue - authentication sessions lost

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6

When using Laravel 6.17 and upgrading to a newer version than 6.17, for example 6.18.43, the logged in sessions are all lost. All users have to authenticate again.

When downgrading back to 6.17, all authentication sessions are restored.

Is there a way to circumvent losing the authentication sessions while upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: As you can read [here](https://blog.laravel.com/security-release-laravel-61827-7220) it is not possible: _"Upgrading to these versions will invalidate any existing cookies issued by your application; therefore, your application's users will need to re-authenticate."_

Comment: where do you store your sessions?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed due to the security release from 6.18.29. Is there any way to circumvent this? Or is re-authentication the only safe and secure way?

Comment: @J.Bek Hard to tell what you would have to do to prevent the invalidation of the cookies and what side effects it could have, in my opinion the only proper way of doing the update would be with re-authentication.